# Malformed Expression error when using java 8 stream in mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am getting Malformed Expression error when using java 8 stream in my expression component . here is my mule esb code :

```
 <expression-component>
        java.util.ArrayList mylist = new java.util.ArrayList();
        mylist.add("ddddfffg");
        payload = mylist;
        payload = mylist.stream().foreach(a -> System.out.println(a)));
     </expression-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably MEL does not support stream api